# IDEA: How to create toString() using superclass

Tags: intellij-idea

If `A extends B`, using `IntelliJ` idea, how can i generate `toString()` using B's public (or protected) methods automatically.

In this example, how can i include public methods from the FileRow?

[image]

Comment: No idea, but recommend you add the java tag.  You'll get more people to look at your question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a template to use `super.toString()`, but there is no way to reference superclass members directly. It may be worth [submitting a new request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA) for this feature.

Comment: Feature request submitted. Thank you

Comment: @Jam mind linking it? (is it this? http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-93029 marked as resolved but I don't see the feature anyway)

Answer (score 3):

This issue is reported in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-93029

It is marked as resolved with fix version 2017.1 (build 171.1161): it's gonna come out soon :)

Answer (score 3):

Simply just change the Template that generates the `toString()` method:

Alt+Insert to open the String Generator window -> Click `Settings` -> choose `Templates` tab.

Then copy your desired template to a new template and
add the superclass `toString` part before the `return` statement.

```
   #if ($class.hasSuper)
     stringBuilder.append(super.toString());
   #end
```